# is PPTP VPN server supposed to work in DD-WRT 19342 (or later) big build? with a mac OS 10.8.2 client?

Tags: vpn, osx-mountain-lion, dd-wrt, pptp

Following up on some confusing comments in the DD-WRT forums, see http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=167815
(with a screenshot of settings)

In the model-specific thread I learnt that my VPN issues are unlikely to be model-specific after all, so I could have dared to post it here in the first place. 
http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=736784

Sticking to the wiki for my Linksys E900, I currently have eko's 19342 big. Are the VPN servers supposed to work there? If not, is there a newer version where they are?

By the way, the Mac OS VPN client complains about communication problems, if this helps anyone. (So it is not an authentication issue, e.g.. Though I was worried that I somehow misunderstand Krikkit's comment from 2006: "The admin password of the router is inserted into chap-secrets by default!")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this build did not have working VPN servers, neither PPTP nor OpenVPN.

I upgraded to build dd-wrt.v24-20548_NEWD-2_K2.6_mini-nv64k, and I have the PPTP server working (OpenVPN unavailable), though I have puzzlingly slow and asymmetric bandwidth: [how to troubleshoot asymmetric speed PPTP VPN speed? (downlink to client is slow, the server bandwidth up, and there is no encryption overhead)](https://superuser.com/questions/543665/how-to-troubleshoot-asymmetric-speed-pptp-vpn-speed-downlink-to-client-is-slow)