# how to troubleshoot asymmetric speed PPTP VPN speed? (downlink to client is slow, the server bandwidth up, and there is no encryption overhead)

Tags: networking, vpn, bandwidth, dd-wrt, pptp

I hope I have a general question motivated by my specific problem: I have acceptable upload speeds and unacceptable download speeds on my VPN while I think both endpoints have quite some bandwidth in both directions.

I have a PPTP VPN between a DD-wrt router as server (recent build) and Mac OS 10.8.2 as client, without encryption.

Though the server is on a residential ISP (promising 30 Mb/s down, 10 Mb/s up) a continent away, I still have a link from client to server of 500-1500 Kb/s, and even worse, tragic, appalling 30-70 Kb/s link from server to client.

Bottlenecks on my side cannot be the problem.

Though the router is underpowered, I don't expect that much overhead without encryption.

What is there to hope or do, before I simply blame the DD-WRT build again?

Comment: If it were me, I would try connecting 2 machines without VPN, by means of some FTP and test speeds both ways. If they were normal, then blame DD-WRT. Anyway, I read somewhere, when I was setting OpenVPN up, that you could lower MTU to e.g. 1400 in case of slowdowns or unresponsiveness, but i may be wrong about this.

Comment: @Kitet, thanks, the link is fast between the endpoints otherwise. I could get 350 Kb/s in the end from router to client, and 1.5Mb/s from client to router. But if the router is underpowered, maybe I should turn more features off? See http://superuser.com/questions/543985/barebones-features-for-a-dd-wrt-router-acting-as-pptp-server