# barebones features for a DD-WRT router acting as PPTP server

Tags: router, vpn, dd-wrt, pptp

I have a little router (Linksys E900) only to act as a VPN server. I have a decent router behind it, handling radio anyway. So I am happy to relegate any other CPU-intensive stuff to the bigger router, if it is expected make a difference in VPN performance in the slower one. (I am currently getting much slower throughput, esp. from router to client, than the endpoints' connections could explain.)

What (or where) is a list of features on by default that would be worth turning off?

Keep DHCP, remote management and PPTP server only? What else drains resources?

Thanks!

PS:
A relevant DD-WRT forum thread is under http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=737253#737253
My SuperUser question about the asymmetric VPN speed itself is under [how to troubleshoot asymmetric speed PPTP VPN speed? (downlink to client is slow, the server bandwidth up, and there is no encryption overhead)](https://superuser.com/questions/543665/how-to-troubleshoot-asymmetric-speed-pptp-vpn-speed-downlink-to-client-is-slow)